# Best world destinations for dating - a website?

Tags: online-resources, destinations

During a recent trip to Zacatecas, Mexico, I noticed many people (particularly women) staring at me.  There was also a notable lack of other Caucasians around, even in comparison to Guadalajara, Mexico, where I have spent significant time (and had relatively fewer stares).  This lead to a conversation with a Mexican friend of mine who admitted that she, and other Mexican women, tend to find American men more attractive, both physically, and relationally.

So this is the lead-in to my tongue-in-cheek question:

Are there any resources I can use to find out where in the world I am the most attractive?  Or stated another way: Where should I travel if I want to find the easiest date?

I envision a search engine that allows input something like:

> I am a **[man]** from **[the USA]** who speaks **[English]** as a primary language, and am interested in **[single]**  **[women]**.

And it would then show me a list of localities (at least countries, if not regions/cities) where single women are especially attracted to people in my demographic.

Comment: If you're a man from any *rich* country, women in poorer countries will generally find you more interesting, regardless of exact nationality. Beyond that, it's not about your nationality, but personal characteristics (e.g. being non-disgusting and speaking the local language always help).

Comment: @Jonik: Of course having a good personality is important... And I hope that whenever I have a date, this is the primary reason. :)  Even so, I don't think attraction to foreigners can be boiled down to _money_, either. If that was the only important factor, then I wouldn't have noticed such a difference between two cities in Mexico.

Comment: That also doesn't answer the question for other demographics. Where would an American woman be most likely to find a date? Where could a Latin-American man find a date? Or a Chinese man?

Comment: If you mapped out who's attractive where you'd have a kickass Slashdot-and-BoingBoing-ready PhD thesis idea. Or you can ask the OkCupid blog if this is something they'd be willing to investigate using their big dataset: http://blog.okcupid.com/

Comment: This could be another Travel SE business idea ;)

Comment: Maybe the [tag:sex] tag needs to be extended. I don't see any value in a separate [tag:dating] tag. Anyway for me this is an open ended list question, a bit off topic, and not very good. Specific questions would be better.

Comment: @Flimzy - I think the reason that in certain cities in Mexico you are more 'attractive' is that they are smaller and attract less 'foreigners'. I love Zacatecas and it has many tourists, but Guadalajara is much more cosmopolitan.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not sure if dating is a synonym for sex for everyone

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: "tag synonyms are not English language synonyms - they are topics that naturally group together" And we can name them whatever we want to cover the related stuff in the group.

Comment: Hahaha :-)))) You made my day :-) with this question... Anyway, looking at your avatar... honestly, you look so unusual that I would be also looking at you and I swear it doesn't mean anything sexual :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, here's what OkCupid did with a related if edgier question: which races reply more to which other races? (http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/your-race-affects-whether-people-write-you-back/) The data is all from the OkCupid userbase, which is probably mostly in the US. I've emailed them a link to your question; perhaps they'll take it up :)

Comment: @VMAtm: If more of my questions had final/complete/authoritative answers, I would gladly accept them.

Comment: @Tomas: I try to look and behave in an unusual fashion whenever possible... so yes, that may well be why I was being stared at :)

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The two aren't synonymous, but they would be fairly synonymous for someone who is in a given location for a limited amount of time.

Comment: The term *dating* is a vague euphemism and difficult to work with. If you're looking for *sex* (of paid or unpaid variety), that makes the question much more tractable. If you're looking for *marriage*, that's quite a minefield.

Comment: You'd have to include more data (height, weight, complexion, etc) to make it realistic because tastes vary around the world and that becomes a very complex multi-dimensional problem. I know two blond male friends who went to Spain because they said *blond guys get the girls there* and a Latina friend of mine admitted that *pale skin and a foreign accent are the most attractive for most women in South America*.

Comment: I don't know man. It would be nice to also exclude countries where STD rates are above your personal risk level....

Answer (score 4):

One strategy could be to go to an area where there is a noticeable higher number of women than men (or the other way around). If there is a lack of suitable partners in town, people lower their expectations and take what they can get. So dating should be easier.

There are many places in the world where there are more men than women, but not so many where there are more women than men. On top of my head I remember Irkutsk and other Siberian towns because many men move to Western Russia for work.

Comment: Approximately how skewed was the ratio in places like Irkutsk?

Comment: I don't know numbers, and it was not really noticeable on the street, but the locals there told me about it. So I guess it wasn't the best example for my point.

Comment: I overheard a discussion once where some guy was telling others that single men like them should go to Bosnia, which has a "deficit" of men due to relatively recent wars. Also, I think [HS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsingin_Sanomat) ran a story about Latvian women having a hard time finding decent, educated men.