# Are there any women-only places in the world?

Tags: culture, factoids, where-on-earth, destinations, female-travellers

It looks like reports of a women-only city in Saudi Arabia are [greatly exaggerated](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/has-saudi-arabia-announced-plans-for-a-woman-only-city). But are there any other places in the world where the population is entirely or almost entirely female?

The place doesn't have to be particularly large, but there has to be a cause of it being mostly female. A town with a population of five where all five happened to be female wouldn't count. Ideally, the place shouldn't just consist of a single institution. For example, a single convent far away from civilization wouldn't really count.

If males aren't allowed into the place at all, then having displays or exhibits about the place available nearby would be good.

In case anyone is wondering, this is not a duplicate of [Best world destinations for dating - a website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4887/best-world-destinations-for-dating) !

Comment: Yes dozens, but I doubt that you will be accepted to sightsee them.

Comment: If there was a badge for asking the weirdest questions all the time, you would definitely deserve one.

Comment: After some consideration I voted to close this question. It really is more a cultural question then that it is a travel-related question

Comment: @Andra I do not agree: there are famous places like Mount Athos where only men can travel, so why not a question on gender-restricted destinations for women?

Comment: I'd say this is too broad.  For example, convents with only nuns - there must be thousands?

Comment: @MarkMayo Should I rephrase the second paragraph where I mention that the place should preferably be more than just a single institution?

Comment: Well skimming I missed that, but now you're asking about communities, rather than travel.  I mean the answer to the question is 'yes', now we're just defining semantics on community size...

Comment: You can probably re-word this question as "Are there destinations only women can travel to?" and mention Mt Athos as your base for comparison. I think this deserves the good old [tag:factoid] tag too.

Comment: @hippietrail yes, Mt. Athos is a notable "men only" destination and clearly on-site for Travel.SE. I don't see any reason why asking if there are any equivalent "women only" destinations could be off-topic or overly broad. The OP is probably not asking about women's bathrooms and locker rooms and things like that, which exist everywhere.

Comment: @MarkMayo it's incorrect that men are not permitted to visit convents - I was allowed to visit a Catholic convent. I was limited to certain rooms and was not allowed to enter the living areas, but that's different from being barred from the facility.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: I have no complaint against this question. I was offering some suggestions to help prevent it getting closed back in the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may know Iran is being managed by Islamic rules so there are many separated parts for men and women in mosques and buses and woman and man-only schools and nowadays classrooms are being divided according to the sex of students at universities too!

In order to tourism aspect it is interesting to know there are woman-only beaches for women in Persian Gulf beaches and Caspian sea because all beaches according to Islamic rules are man-only when you decide to swim! But surely you can walk along shores with Islamic cover as a woman but not with a swimsuit!

[image]
<sup>[smh.com.au](http://www.smh.com.au/travel/from-hijab-to-skimpy-bikini-behind-the-walled-beach-20120301-1u51q.html)</sup>

[image]
<sup>[blogs.reuters.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjCiL.jpg)</sup>

There are also many sport stadiums which are man-only in general but while there is a national or international (for example International Muslim Women Games) game they turn into woman-only stadiums during the game.

Comment: I'm surprised at "all beaches according to Islamic rules are man-only when you decide to swim" - I've seen women swimming in public beaches in several Islamic countries, often wearing niqabs (which looks difficult to swim in!) - though these weren't super-strict countries and, now I think about it, I've never seen men and women swimming together, not even from same family group.

Answer (score 19):

The [Riyadh Women University](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Nora_bint_Abdul_Rahman_University) campus in Riyadh, Saudi Arabia could qualify as an answer to your question. Its new campus can accommodate 40,000 (female-only) students and 12,000 (female-only) employees. There are only women because of the [Saudi laws of sex segregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_rights_in_Saudi_Arabia#Sex_segregation). [Inaugurated in June 2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_efmT-QfFFY&feature=related), it spreads over 8 million square meters (2,800 km²) with 800 buildings and ten gates between Riyadh and the university campus, the total built up area being around 3 million square metres. In addition to the university buildings (13 faculties, a library of 6 million volumes, administration, research centers, laboratories) and housing for university staff and students, it features mosques, schools and kindergarten for children, as well as sport and recreation facilities. It also includes a nursery for young mothers and as well as a training hospital with 700 beds. The large campus and community is served by an 11.5 km automated metro. It is one of the ten largest universities in the world and the largest university for women.

The expansion of the campus was done in a record time of two years supported by 75,000 construction workers and latest building machinery and methodologies, at a cost of 11.5 billion US dollars.

You can find videos on YouTube giving you a look [at the construction works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GajUMrBCPqs&feature=related) or [at a small-scale reproduction and at the inside of a few buildings](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANiDF2vjf7g&feature=related) now that their construction has been completed.

Comment: EWHA University in Seoul: 20k, women only

Comment: @greg121 why not write up some info on it and make that a new answer?

Comment: Most universities permit tourism on campus - I've never seen one that didn't. Some schools have restrictions on building entry and facility use (e.g. no swimming pool usage for tourists), but allow anyone to walk around the grounds. Do these schools have gates barring men from entering the campus, or is the women-only restriction more a restriction on enrollment as a formal student?

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Saudi Arabia has a strict application of Sharia law. Men and women do not mingle if they're not married or related. The Women University is strictly women-only, for students, staff and visitors.

Comment: *kindergarten for the children* — what if the woman has a baby boy?  Can he attend the nursery / kindergarten?

Comment: @gerrit: Yes, small children do not have to be segregated by sex.

Answer (score 14):

Both Buddhist and Christian traditions have women-only convents or monasteries, also known as [nunneries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aNunneries). Some of these are nowadays partially open to visitors, such as the [Chi Lin Nunnery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Lin_Nunnery) in Hong Kong or the [Convent of Las Descalzas Reales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convent_of_Las_Descalzas_Reales) in Madrid. I don't know whether these are the most authentic or noteworthy, though.

An entirely different possibility: in some poorer countries like [Armenia](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-14386472), a large percentage of the men seek work abroad while the women stay at home, which can result in villages being almost entirely populated by women.

Answer (score 11):

> The place doesn't have to be particularly large, but there has to be a
>   cause of it being mostly female.

At the (gorgeous) Pärnu beach in Estonia, there's a somewhat large section for women.

[image]
<sup>Photo by me, July 2012</sup>

The sign doesn't *explicitly* state it, but apparently men should stay out, sadly. :)

Comment: Maybe not what OP sought, but fits the current wording of the question. :)